# How do I print out the instance variable x from my Main class using a 'Second' class?

Tags: java, class, variables, instance

```
package com.company;
public class Main {
    int x = 5;
    }
```

//below is a separate class I have created to run my code in:

```
package com.company;

import java.sql.SQLOutput;

class Second {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main myObj = new Main();
        System.out.println(myObj.x);
    }

}
```

This is the error message I get when I run my second class

```
Error: Main method not found in class com.company.Main, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Comment: And what problem are you running into with the code presented?

Comment: Hi John, sorry forgot to add, it should be on the question now, cheers

Comment: are you sure you are running the correct file?

Comment: The error message suggests that you are trying to run class `com.company.Main` as a Java application.  Despite the name, it's not one. The main class of your application, as presented in the question, is `com.company.Second`.  Run *that*.

Comment: Snap, yeap I just figured it out - many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found out - I was running my class Second and I needed to run class Main as that is where my main() method is located!
Cheers anyway